# How do I connect to the localhost using UnboundID LDAP SDK?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

How do I connect to the localhost using UnboundID LDAP SDK? I would think it is pretty straight forward, but maybe not. I connect just fine using the following code, but I would like to have the option to just use the locahost connection and not have to authenticate.

With the connection, I perform a series of add/remove/modify, which works fine with the below connection.

```
public LDAPConnection connect(LdapConnectionModel connectionModel)
{
    this.connectionModel = connectionModel;
    try
    {
        // Determine is SSL port was specified
        int port = connectionModel.isSslEnabled() ? SSL_PORT : PORT;

        // Determined bind DN
        String bindDN = connectionModel.getUsername() + "@" + connectionModel.getDomain();

        // Connect
        connection = new LDAPConnection(connectionModel.getHost(), port, bindDN, String.valueOf(connectionModel.getPassword()));

        // Clear out our password
        connectionModel.setPassword(new char[] {});
    }
    catch (LDAPException e)
    {
        LOG.warning("CONNECTION FAILED: " + e.getMessage());
        LOG.warning(e.getMessage());
    }
    return connection;
}
```

For example, getting a connection like this is fine, but then I get this error:
"In order to perform this operation a successful bing must be completed on the connection."

```
// Connect
connection = new LDAPConnection("localhost",389);
```

Comment: What does using a server listening for connections on the `localhost` have to do with whether the LDAP client authenticates to the server? LDAP clients should authenticate to server to achieve the authorization state required for the server to perform the LDAP operations on behalf of the client, whether the server is listening for connections on the `localhost` or somewhere else. Possibly I don't understand the question.

Comment: @TerryGardner thank you for the reply. Please see my edit with an example of what I am looking for. I am new to LDAP so perhaps I dont understand the usage of the SDK

Comment: What you listed in your edit will work if there is an LDAP server listening for non-secure client connections on port `389` on the `localhost`. Do you already have the server running?

Comment: Please read the updated comment on that connection. It does get that connection, but states I must have a bind to complete an operation. yes the server is running. I connect fine to it using the Ip Address and the credentials. But for instance, if my application is running on the actual server, I shouldn't have to authenticate, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference *where*, or on which host, the directory server is running. When an LDAP client connects to a server, that connection is *unauthenticated*. LDAP clients must use the BIND request to request the server change the authorization state of the connection to a state that permits the operations that the LDAP client desires.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Authentication Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/authentication-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)